# The module has not been deployed. Tomcat 8.0 and Netbeans 8.0.2

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans

I am trying to connect Tomcat 8.0 with Netbeans 8.0.2 and run a project with these 2.

I have set Tomcat correctly and from Services->Servers I can see it running.When I try to build the project I am working on it is beeing built without any fails but when I try and run it it comes with this message:

`C:\Users\Aris\Desktop\ted\Ted_auctions\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1052: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.`

Although Server Log doesn't provide any info I am looking into build-impl.xml @ line 1052 and here is what it says:

```
<target if="netbeans.home" name="-run-deploy-nb">
<nbdeploy clientUrlPart="${client.urlPart}" debugmode="false" forceRedeploy="${forceRedeploy}"/>
</target>
```

1052 line beeing the middle one..Anyone has any idea why deployment fails?I am sorry if this is already answered elsewhere I just couldn't find any other solution yet.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you think that "the server log doesn't provide any info"? The only reason that this is the case is that the deployment URL is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry this is the server log,I was supposed to post this too..

```
Jun 06, 2015 2:39:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Jun 06, 2015 2:39:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Jun 06, 2015 2:39:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@317f2eba')
Jun 06, 2015 2:41:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextDestroyed()
Jun 06, 2015 2:41:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextDestroyed()
Jun 06, 2015 2:41:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Jun 06, 2015 2:41:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Jun 06, 2015 2:41:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@4ba3b734')
Jun 06, 2015 4:18:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextDestroyed()
Jun 06, 2015 4:18:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextDestroyed()
Jun 06, 2015 7:16:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Jun 06, 2015 7:16:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Jun 06, 2015 7:16:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@13a57a45')
Jun 06, 2015 9:18:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextDestroyed()
Jun 06, 2015 9:18:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextDestroyed()
Jun 06, 2015 9:19:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Jun 06, 2015 9:19:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Jun 06, 2015 9:19:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@5c523672')
```